# How to simulate Arima-Garch models in R?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, jupyter-irkernel

I was trying to find how may I simulate (i.e. generate ARIMA in the mean model and a GARCh in the variance model) in R.

I tried searching online but I only found how to fit such a model using

```
spec <- ugarchspec( variance.model = list(   
                                            model = "sGARCH", 
                                             garchOrder = c(1, 1),
                                             submodel = NULL, 
                                             external.regressors = NULL, 
                                             variance.targeting = FALSE),

                                             mean.model = list(  armaOrder = c(1, 1), 
                                                                 include.mean = TRUE, 
                                                                 archm = FALSE,
                                                                 archpow = 1, 
                                                                 arfima = FALSE, 
                                                                 external.regressors = NULL, 
                                                                 archex = FALSE),
                                                                 distribution.model = "norm", 
                                                                 start.pars = list(), 
                                                                 fixed.pars = list()
                    )
```

Then I write

```
garch <- ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = data, solver.control = list(trace=0))
```

This is obviously fitting and not simulating i.e. generating random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for the `ugarchsim` function which takes the result of `ugarchfit` as an input.

Check out [this example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-realized-garch-model/).

Comment: yes metasequia (thank you very much), but I do not know how to use it? like if I want to generate say an ARMA(2,1)-Garch(1,2) how may I do so with ugarchsim

Comment: Please consult the documentation and some examples. If you encounter specific errors that your attempts cannot resolve, then consider writing an SO question with reproducible code, the error, and what you've tried.